# WHERE query with IN on json\jsonb field

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have field on some table (products), like "data". This field contains, for example, next data:

```
[{"text" : "Text one"}, {"text" : "Text two"}, {"text" : "Text three"}]
```

I need to be able find products, where json objects inside each object array on "data" field contain "text" : "Text one" or "text" : "Text two". Generally, I need to do IN query, but inside json "data" field -> array -> object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data:

```
create table products(id int, data json);
insert into products values
(1, '[{"text" : "Text one"}, {"text" : "Text two"}, {"text" : "Text three"}]'),
(2, '[{"text" : "Text four"}, {"text" : "Text two"}, {"text" : "Text three"}]');
```

Use `json_array_elements()`:

```
select distinct id, data::jsonb
from (
    select * 
    from products p, 
    json_array_elements(data)
    ) s
where value->>'text' in ('Text one', 'Text two')
order by id;

 id |                                 data                                  
----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | [{"text": "Text one"}, {"text": "Text two"}, {"text": "Text three"}]
  2 | [{"text": "Text four"}, {"text": "Text two"}, {"text": "Text three"}]
(2 rows)
```

Note: `data` must be cast to `jsonb` to be used in `distinct`.