# PostgreSQL - Where In JSONB

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I'm having a hard time querying jsonb data. I'm not used to dealing with jsonb types in postgres . Is it possible to do a **WHERE IN** on a jsonb field?

I have data like this

```
id | act   | act_id |      from_ids       |     object_ids       | post_date
2    post      1      {"2":"1494308197"}    {"items":["104564"]}   1494308197
```

I'm trying to do something like this below to find any ids in the from_ids column where the id is the key.

```
SELECT an.* FROM activity_network an, jsonb_each(an.from_ids) d WHERE d.key->> in ('2');
```

But obviously that doesn't work. I tried various forms.

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188297/where-query-with-in-on-json-jsonb-field) but it doesn't work for what I need as it gets the value and I need to get `key` using `IN`.

Not sure how to use these jsonb functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much simpler than that:

```
SELECT an.*
FROM activity_network an
WHERE an.from_ids ?| ARRAY['2'];
```

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html).

The following index can speed up such a query:

```
CREATE INDEX ON activity_network USING gin (from_ids);
```

Comment: Well look at that. That is simple. Been banging my head for hours. Thanks for the quick one!  It doesn't seem to use the gin index if there is more than one item in the array. Would you happen to know if that can be indexed?

Comment: I have extended the answer to include that information. If you don't see the index used, maybe PostgreSQL thinks that a sequential scan is cheaper. You can `SET enable_seqscan = off` to test if the index *can* be used.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `jsonb_exists` function for that.

```
SELECT an.* FROM activity_network an WHERE jsonb_exists(an.from_ids,'2');
```

The `?` operator described in [the PG documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) maps to that function. I suggest you use it instead if you're using PHP, Java or anything other than C + libpq, because everyone in the world has agreed that `?` stands for positional parameters, except the Postgres team.

Comment: So I actually don't see that function in the documentation. Where did you find it?

Comment: You can find it by running `\doS+` in the psql console. It only lists the corresponding functions when you have the +. It's a few pages down.

Comment: But how to represent it `WHERE products_alias.extras -> 'SIZE' ?| array['91', '38']` with jsonb_exists ? @Laurenz Albe

Comment: @shuba.ivan the `->` operator corresponds to either `jsonb_array_element(array,index)` or `jsonb_object_field(object,field)` in your case.

Comment: but how to should look query `WHERE products_alias.extras -> 'SIZE' ?| array['91', '38']` ?